# matlab spell checker on OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, matlab, spelling

I've seen several threads on this issue for PC, but I'm searching for a Matlab function that will allow me to check the spelling of words in an array on a Mac.  I'm currently using Matlab R2015b.

On File Exchange I found a function (see link below), however this calls ActiveX which to my knowledge is PC only.  Is there a comparable way to call the spell checker from MS Word using Matalab on a mac?

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5378-spellcheck/content/spellcheck.m

Comment: Have you read this [recent blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/12/18/open-and-extensible/) from The MathWorks and tried the code? See also this [follow-up post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2016/01/16/making-code-usable-useful-and-testable/).

Comment: I had not seen it, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have never done anything like this, but your best bet may be to use AppleScript rather than ActiveX. I found the following link that may get you started: http://divvun.no/doc/proof/spelling/testdoc/using-word.html .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.